# Google Calendar API: Update Timezone from UTC to 'Asia/Tokyo'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-calendar-api

I have difficulty in getting correct timezone via Google Calendar API on Ruby on Rails. I user `google-ruby-client`.

result:

```
#<CalendarEvent:0x00007ffa082f49f0
id: 7,
start_at: Tue, 23 Oct 2018 02:00:00 UTC +00:00,
end_at: Tue, 23 Oct 2018 03:00:00 UTC +00:00,
summary: "MTG",
```

code:

```
  calendar = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Calendar.new({ discription: 'random', summary:(email.sub(/@.*/, "")+'-random')})
  service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
  service.authorization = client

  # Generate calendar id
  _calendar = service.insert_calendar(calendar)

  now = Time.now.iso8601
  still = Time.now.since(1.month).iso8601
  items = service.fetch_all do |token|
    service.list_events('primary',
                          single_events: true,
                          order_by: 'startTime',
                          time_min: now,
                          time_max: still,
                          time_zone: 'Asia/Tokyo',
                          page_token: token)
  end

  items.each do |event|        
    calendar_event = CalendarEvent.new(
      uid: event.id,
      start_at: event.start.date_time,
      end_at: event.end.date_time,
      summary: event.summary,
    )
    calendar_event.save
  end
```

I want to get event detail with Asia/Tokyo timezone or UTC +9h, so do you guys have any ideas to stack overflow?

Answer (score 0):

Events are set to the timezone of the calendar itself.  If you do a [calendar.get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) on the calendar itself you can see what timezone its set to.

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"ze8zJIc0rbkO4aY_gGX0swNYq0/WK1K2C9CsAxePbI13h8-KuIOLek\"",
 "id": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
 "summary": "xxxx@gmail.com",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
 "conferenceProperties": {
  "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
   "eventHangout"
  ]
 }
}
```

So when creating your events you will need to take the timezone of the calendar into consideration when setting the event time.   There are a large number of issues relating to creating events with a time zone [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B)